# OS X/Cocoa: Re-prompting the user for permission to use Location Services?

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-location

(I see that the question has been answered in context of iOS but I am working with Cocoa/OS X.)

I am writing an application that utilises Location Services.

When CLLocationManager is first started, the user is given the choice to enable or disable Location Services. In my application, I want to give the user the choice of activating Location Services if they have previously refused it. But, looking at the class reference, I see no way of re-prompting the user for permission. It seems that the user's initial decision stands forever:

> **Important**: In addition to hardware not being available, the user has the option of denying an application’s access to location service data. During its initial uses by an application, the Core Location framework prompts the user to confirm that using the location service is acceptable. If the user denies the request, the CLLocationManager object reports an appropriate error to its delegate during future requests.

Is there a way to reset the authorisation status programmatically?

Comment: @progrmr: That question is about iOS. Answers that are correct on that OS are not necessarily correct on OS X, even within the same framework.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to check the tags, I assumed iOS.